# How can I run a same command in mac terminal for multiple files in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, grep, terminal

How can I run the same command in mac terminal for multiple files in a folder? The files are named like `24538_7#1.fq`, `24538_7#2.fq`, `24538_7#3.fq`, `24538_7#4.fq` and so on.

The commands are:

`sed -n '\|@.*/1|{N;N;N;p;}' 24538_7#2.fq > 24538_7#2_paired1.fq`
`sed -n '\|@.*/2|{N;N;N;p;}' 24538_7#2.fq > 24538_7#2_paired2.fq`

Since filename involves a counter, so, obviously the filenames need to be changed.

I was trying to write command, but I got stuck at renaming the file. 
My effort for the command is below:

```
for file in 24538_7#*.fq; do sed -n '\|@.*/1|{N;N;N;p;}' "$file" > "${file/fq/fq}"; done
```

(PS- I use MacOS)

Comment: Also if you are putting this command in a script (or if you have `interactive_comments` disabled) you will need to quote the `#` to avoid it being interpreted as a comment.

Comment: I'm not able to think how to write it so that the output file gets renamed only without interferring with my original file. Kind of this `24538_7#2.fq > 24538_7#2_paired1.fq` is what I want to accomplish but on multiple files as stated earlier.

Comment: Not copy the files, but run the command on original files and then their output should be made with somehow different name. 
Can you help me @Jesse_b

Comment: You want to run two separate sed commands on each file, each generating it's own output file, correct?

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, that's the plan and if not possible, then, two commands for all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all files are named similarly you can use

```
for file in 24538_7#*.fq; do
    sed -n '\|@.*/1|{N;N;N;p;}' "$file" > "${file%.fq}_paired1.fq"
    sed -n '\|@.*/2|{N;N;N;p;}' "$file" > "${file%.fq}_paired2.fq"
done
```

or (to build on what you've already tried)

```
for file in 24538_7#*.fq; do
    sed -n '\|@.*/1|{N;N;N;p;}' "$file" > "${file/.fq/_paired1.fq}"
    sed -n '\|@.*/2|{N;N;N;p;}' "$file" > "${file/.fq/_paired2.fq}"
done
```

**Warning**: This will only work for your specific situation and for your specific filenames.

Comment: Can you suggest me some platform or some book maybe, where I can learn such things?
Thanks btw:)

Comment: @AkhilVerma `man bash`, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html, https://www.bash.academy, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ. And Google of course :-)